# How do I specify a clang-format file?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-clang, clang-format

I just built clang 5.0.0 on a Redhat 6 machine and tried to run clang-format. I'm unable to get the -style option to read in a style file. Here's an example of a set of commands that I think should work:

```
./clang-format -style=llvm -dump-config > .llvm-format
./clang-format -style=.llvm-format ~/myFile.cc
```

When I run this command I get the following error:

```
Invalid value for -style
```

It appears to find and use .clang-format when placed in a parent directory as expect. The built-in types also work:

```
./clang-format -style=Mozilla ~/myFile.cc
```

The problem, then, is that I can't specify explicitly a .clang-format file to use. Is this a problem with my build or am I misusing clang-format oir misunderstanding the documentation?

Comment: Updated this bug: https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=20753

Comment: 100% working solution on StackOverflow here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56883170/beautify-c-files-in-vscode/74138528#74138528

Answer (score 111):

I got confused by that too. When they tell you to use the flag `-style=file` they literally mean for you to type out `-style=file`, NOT `-style=<path/to/actual/filename>`.

With this flag, `clang-format` will look for a file called `.clang-format` in the directory of the target file. If it doesn't find any it will `cd ..` and try again. There doesn't seem to be a way to tell `clang-format` to use a file that is not named exactly `.clang-format`.

The correct usage for your example would be:

```
./clang-format -style=llvm -dump-config > ~/.clang-format
./clang-format -style=file ~/myFile.cc
```

Comment: This is by far one of the dumbest implementations I've ever heard of. At least I got my daily dose of crying...

Comment: Should I use `--style=file` or `-style=file`?

Comment: two dashes (--style-file) is what is shown in usage, but it seems that both are accepted.

Answer (score 21):

(updated 2022-02-25) [clang 14.0.0-RC1](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-14.0.0-rc1) or later now supports `-style=file:<format_file_path>` after this change ["Add option to explicitly specify a config file"](https://reviews.llvm.org/D72326) entered the [main branch](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/). It's [documented here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html). This worked for me:

```
.\LLVM14.0.0RC1\bin\clang-format.exe test.cpp -style=file:my_clang_format.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Just an additional hint:
(in my case on Windows 10)
- if you dump the config to a file, check the ascii coding afterwards, e.g. in Notepad++
- the .clang-format file has to be utf8 without BOM !!! (you can convert it in Notepadd++) 
- otherwise you get an error like "YAML:1:4: error: Got empty plain scalar"
- place the .clang-format file in the same folder or in a parent directory of the code-file.c

A correct command line call to format the code-file.c would look like that:
clang-format.exe -style=file -i C:\path\code-file.c