# Beautify C++ files in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode 1.35.5.

I have two projects in the workspace, one `.js` files and another with `.cpp` files.

When I want to beautify a `.cpp` file, here is the following pop up :

[image]

From  `File -> Preferences -> Extensions`, here are the following enabled extensions :

- Beautify from HookyQR 1.5.0
- C/C++ from Microsoft 0.23.1
- CMake 0.0.17
- ESLint 1.9.0

How can I use the Beautify extension for C++ files ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- Open *"Show Command Palette"* with <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, then write *"Format Document With..."* then select *c/c++* selection.
- Or first select *"default"* then select *"c/c++"*. In second way when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, you can format your C++ file.

Answer (score 9):

- Simple go to command palette using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- search *"format"*
- and select *"Format document with"*
- and simply select "*C/C++*"

No need for any third party formatter. And if you want to use them then just go to this link and follow the steps: *[Description to install clang-formatter](https://www.dynamsoft.com/codepool/vscode-format-c-code-windows-linux.html)*

And while installing clang make sure to add a path to current user or to all users after installing both the clang software and the extension in VSCode. The use is same as I mention for default C/C++ formatter.

Answer (score 3):

To beautify C++ code you need the `Clang-Format` extension. After installing it, the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will work in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I installed that set it to default, and now Alt+Shift+F does nothing. -- After I uninstalled it and put it back on the default MS one, it finally started working.  Dunno what was going on there.

Comment: C/C++ by Microsoft vscode extension is now able to format well.

Comment: Any way to have clang-format installed in a container instead of the host machine and have this extension run? I couldn't find a relevant value in the settings JSON

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 just installing Clang-Format vs-code extension will not work. do check all the steps are you following as I also posted the answer to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56883170/beautify-c-files-in-vscode/74138528#74138528. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The VSCode C/C++ extension includes `clang-format` automatically, so you can simply run <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and your C++ will format.

Then to use it more extensively I opened the C++ settings JSON (Settings→`cpp`→`Open JSON settings`), removed `editor.defaultFormatter` (which was prettier for me), added format on save and format on  paste, and it worked like a charm.

Here's the docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide#_code-formatting

Answer (score 1):

#### To auto-format C/C++ code on vs code using Clang

**Step 1:** Install Clang-Format vs code extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xaver.clang-format.

**Step 2:** Download & Install **LLVM builds** (32 or 64-bit version) from here https://llvm.org/builds/
[image]

**Step 3:** After installing it, search for **clang-format executable** in vs code settings & under **Clang-format: Executable** set it the path where LLVM buids you have installed like in my case I installed it on default path therefore I have used the path of the **clang-format.exe** path as ***'C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang-format.exe'***

[image]

**Step 4:** Now its almost done, just right click in any **C/C++** file and select **Format Document** or use shortcut **Shift + Alt + F** (for windows)[image]

**Step 5:** There may come conflicts between other **code formatter** you may be already using for some other types of files like java, javascript, c# etc, like in my case I was using **prettier** as well, if the below pop-up is shown then click to **configure**  & select **Clang-Format**.
[image]

[image]

all done now just re-try **Format Document** or **Shift + Alt + F** this time it will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

To format cpp files in vscode, the file must be saved as a cpp file first. Formatting javascript/java code works as expected with out the file being saved. C++ utilities seem to be buggy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Did below to solve this:

1. I installed below `C/C++ Microsoft` extension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools

2. Then, right-click a c++ file > Format document with > C/C++ (default)
3. Later, `Alt + Shift + F` to Format document works great on Windows OS